# Implementing DSR protocol in Veins Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

i want to implement DSR protocol in with veins framework, but the problem is veins have no DSR protocol and INET lacks DSRC protocol, i need both to create a VANET that uses DSRC and DSR for routing. can any one guide me please

Answer (score 0):

You can use Veins for that purpose, it will give you all the required tools to simulate a DSRC network. VeinsLTE provides both DSRC and LTE capabilities vehicular networking simulations in OMNeT++.

Both of the tools have buit-in examples which you can use as a reference point to write the algorithm that you want: DSR

Veins example: https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc

VeinsLTE example: https://github.com/floxyz/veins-lte/tree/master/veins/src/veins/modules/heterogeneous/application